# query help to ignore duplicates

Tags: sql

Can I get some help with this query?

Field - ISNULL( tc1.TypeCode, '') + '|'

I need NONE to show in tc1.typecode only if there is no other value in there...right now I am seeing same name twice ...for e.g.one with NONE & one with Navy.

+[Capture]

[image: 1]

Comment: That is not a query.  At best, it might be an expression.  What are you trying to do?  Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: Picture of the output is in the CAPTURE link, if you could see it.

Comment: Please share sample data with your complete query.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you want this :

```
select Name , MAX(NULLIF(Status, 'NONE')) status
from table
group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to group by `name` and aggregate:

```
select 
    [name],
    IsNull(Max(NullIf([status], 'NONE')),'NONE') [status]
from t
group by [name]
```

You can also achieve the same with `row_number`

```
select [name], [status] from (
    select * , Row_Number() over(partition by [name] order by case when [status]='NONE' then 99 end) rn
    from t
)t
where rn=1
```